# Select multiple variables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have the following problem.

I have a `receipts table` with several columns, among others I have 2 columns `'receipt_id'` and other `'status'`.

`'Status'` can take the following values: `'active'` and `'unpaid'`.

I would like to run a query to have an output of the following ratio `(lets call it 'RR') RR=active/(active+unpaid)`

I've tried to make 'RR' as a variable and then input the arguments with their conditions using 'AS' function.

Also I've tried to make the following:

select count(distinct r.user_id) from receipts as r where r.status='active' as active, count(distinct r.user_id) from receipts as r where r.status='unpaid' as unpaid

(in order to get two different columns and the make the ratio 'RR' with a simple formula).

None of this is working...

Could someone please help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sql does not have variables. I am confused

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your sample code uses `count(distinct)`, but your question statement does not require that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation.  I think this is the simplest method:

```
select avg(r.status = 'active')
from receipts r
where r.status in ('active', 'unpaid');
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, That was pretty useful!!